# Connecting NIFI to Posgresql instance java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to set up a simple test in Apache Nifi to connect to an existing PostgreSQL instance.  I'm able to connect outside of nifi using other tools like dBeaver, and am fairly sure my connection string is proper.  I have tried putting the postgresql jdbc driver in all sorts of places, but still keep seeing the "No suitable driver" error.  I'll include some screenshots of my DBCPConnectionPool controller as well as my stack traces.

I have seen other posts like this, but none of them seem to lead to any solutions for me.  Any help is appreciated.

[image: DBCPConnectionPool]

Stack Trace

```
19-11-05 23:50:09,933 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL ExecuteSQL[id=3d68fb42-016e-1000-0ea4-abcc7dcc2e48] Unable to execute SQL select query select * from records; due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:postgres://salt.db.elephantsql.com:5432/oickotoy'. No FlowFile to route to failure: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:postgres://salt.db.elephantsql.com:5432/oickotoy'
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:postgres://salt.db.elephantsql.com:5432/oickotoy'
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:442)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPService.getConnection(DBCPService.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor609.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.AbstractExecuteSQL.onTrigger(AbstractExecuteSQL.java:223)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1176)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:213)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:postgres://salt.db.elephantsql.com:5432/oickotoy'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:472)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:538)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:753)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:438)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.java:68)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Comment: `jdbc:postgresql:`

Comment: sorry, I had tried a bunch of different ways.  jdbs:postgresql gets the same result

Answer (score 0):

What solved this issue for me was oddly enough deleting the Database connection URL (jdbc:postgresql://.....), applying the empty connection string to the controller service, then re-typing the connection string and then applying the now re-typed connection string to the controller service.

Seems like some kind of special character has caused this hiccup

Answer (score 0):

What ended up solving this in the end was a version problem.  I was apparently working on a dev release of Nifi that this was broken in.  After I upgraded to the latest stable release, my problem went away.